# Swift Core Data: Invalid update when deleting row

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

Ok, so I am attempting to delete a conversation from a tableView on my chat app and the app crashes. The error message is as follows:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. 
>   Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of
>   items contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be
>   equal to the number of items contained in that section before the
>   update (3), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
>   with userInfo (null)

From the error message, the numbers "3" is actually the number of messages inside my conversation. In other words in this particular conversation, there are total of 3 messages. The structure and relationship between my Conversation and Message are as follows:

1. Relationship between Conversation and Message is a one-many, ie 1 conversation to many messages
2. I have set delete rule as nullify for destination "Conversation" and inverse "message", and set delete rule as cascade for destination "Message" and inverse "conversation"

My code so far for my chatLogViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

    let selectedConversation = self.activeConversations[indexPath.row]
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    context.delete(selectedConversation)

    do {
        try context.save()
        self.activeConversations.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

I do not quite understand why am I getting this error message. The frustrating matter is that this error does not pop up all the time. It happens occasionally, but frequent enough.

Is anyone able to advice?

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure out the issue behind this? I am getting similar error. It happens occassionally and not all the time

Comment: @OsamaNaeem No I did not. Do let me know if you are able to resolve this too

Comment: I have not been able to replicate this error again after making sure that a tableview which was connected to frc (but with a different entity that had one to one relationship with main tableview) had beginUpdates() and endupdates() in controllerdidchange and controllerwillchange! 
But then again, the error is way to rare which makes it tough to get a permanent fix.